# VBA script breaks while cutting range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, cut

I've been struggling with what seems to be a corrupted file.
Basically it is a feature that allows the user to get an specific (and variable) range of cells and move them to the active cell (a "place here" kind of command).
The code works in any new file and I'm sure that's not the problem because it worked fine.
For some reason, when the file was being used by other team members it got corrupted and now it breaks after the line. It actually shifts the cells positions (the cut method works) but it stops the macro right at that line (and there's more to do in the script).

```
If c_finish <> 0 And c_start <> 0 Then
    Range(Cells(l, c_start), Cells(l, c_finish)).Cut Destination:=Cells(l, ActiveCell.Column)
    hold_auto_updates = True
    Call format_lines(l, l)
    hold_auto_updates = False
End If
```

The line starting with "Range..." simply breaks the code from nowhere.
Does anyone knows what can be happening to the file? Savings with other versions (other patches of the same year)? Conflicts with conditional formatting, etc. etc.

Comment: What does "breaks the code" mean? An error message? If so, what is the message?

Comment: It simply stops processing the code and does nothing more. No error message. It is just as the Range... cut line was the last line of the script. The main point is that the script was working perfectly. I'm pretty sure it is caused by some sort of file "distortion" when saved by other users because there was some strange date format modifications in one column.

Comment: Code doesn't just "stop." What happens when you step through with F8?

Comment: I'm with you! I am just as astonished as your sentence. It should NOT just stop, but it does. :( I have been coding VBA Macros for about 17 years and have not experienced this kind of break, at least not without any error message.

Comment: So what happens with `F8`?

Comment: It goes step by step and just at the line "Range.... cut..." when I press F8 once again the yellow line disapears. The cells are shifted from position and the VBA goes back to iddle (nothing more being executed).

Comment: What happens if source and destination of the cut overlap?

Comment: The origin is moved to the destination regardless of the relationship. Even if they are the same cell it works. And the code stops at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem.
The sub-script "format_lines" adds some complex conditional formatting (using a user defined function to determine the format). It is applied to the cells being manipulated by the cut command.
When removing all conditional formatting BEFORE cutting it works fine.
I'll be revising the code in order to understand why the line was breaking with no warning. Even though it does not explain why the code stopped working after other users interacted with it, I have some better understanding of where the problem is.